# How does Google Analytics calculate the number of Unique Visitors for any arbitrary timespan?

Tags: google-analytics, data-mining, analytics

Note that Unique Visitors is not a value you can sum.
If I had 10 unique visitors on Sunday and 15 on Monday it doesnt mean I had 25 uniques on Sun-Mon...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that GA does not do this (i.e., calculate Unique Visitors for an arbitrary time span)--Unique Visitor counts are *specific to* a given time period.

Put another way, the answer--which is easier to see when you retrieve data via the API and your call includes a data range--is that the *Unique Visitor count is tied to the time period specified in your query* (API call or GA Browser view).

For instance, for one of our Sites, GA reports 2,316,674 Unique Visitors for 2009; if i sum the UV counts for each of the 12 months then i get 2,844,912.

This view is [reiterated](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=3803d8132b3f7e6d&hl=en) in the GA Forums, and in Blog posts on the subject, e.g., in the excellent [Lunametrics Blog](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2010/07/30/absolute-unique-unique-visitors-google-analytics/).

Comment: In the GA website I can go and pick any possible date range... say, Tuesday two weeks ago to last Thursday. The value of Unique Visitors depends on the selected timespan and pre-calculating all possible combinations is impossible even for Google...

Comment: @Eran doug is completely right here. Google only precalculates certain values, and if you ask it for a number it hasn't calculated, it will recalculate on the fly. That's why some pages with more complex queries load much slower than others. Also, as it gets more and more complex, Google may rely on *sampling* the data rather than providing a full picture of the data. You'll see this if you open up the range to include a very long stretch of time with 6 digits plus of traffic.

Comment: @yc when a report is based on sampling they say that on the report. However when looking at Unique Visitors metric, it doesnt. I tried many different timespans (roughly month long or less) and it never specifically says its based on sampling and it alaways give some number. I find it hard to believe that number is not based on sampling or some kind of formula, and not precalculated (bcz you cant precalculate all combinations). So I wonder how they do it... whats the formula being used?